# Android ListView real time content

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, real-time

I have a simple `listView` with simple adapter and I am getting a new live content (it means data with changed items) every 5 sec. I have to update some rows with new values, so I `clear` adapter and `addAll` in list, but then all list is freezing and scrolling up.

If it's a short list, all is work good, the problem becomes when I have long list with scroll.

Is there better solution for my task? How could I monitor only changed rows and redraw there?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ListView use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html). RecyclerView allows to refresh and add individual elements to list.

[Adapter method item added at position](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int))

Answer (score 0):

So my solution is. As I have abnormal list (I'm getting response from back-end with different values for each row, I must to group it and generate unique layout for each row),  so I've used a TableLayout, I generated each row and put it to `Map`, when I catch new response I check old value with new one and if there are different, I take `View` from `Map` and bind new data.